# 30% chance of hitting, what is the probability that this player gets hits on each of his next 2 bats and then makes an out at the next bat?

Tags: probability

A baseball player has a 30% chance of hitting at any bat, what is the probability that this player gets hits on each of his next 2 at bats and then makes an out (misses) at the next bat?

Would it be 0.063? Because P(hits) = 3/10, and P(miss) = 7/10, I did this: 0.3 x 0.3 x 0.7. However, I'm not sure if this is the right equation to use?

Other possible answers: 0.670, 0.090, or 0.210

Thank you.

Comment: This is good. Indeed, we assume that all the tries are independant, so the probability of hitting the two first times and missing the third is the product of the probabilities, as you computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

The probability of a hit is $30\%=0.3$, so the probability of a miss is $1-30\%=70\%=0.7$.

Assuming that all bats are independent (the outcome of one bat does not affect the other bats), then the probability of hitting the next two bats and missing the third is $0.3\times0.3\times0.7=0.063=6.3\%$.

Note that it is important that the question specified that the player hits his **next 2** bats and misses the **next** bat. If the question did not specify the order and you were just finding the probability of two misses out of three bats, the answer is different.